# How change object key values in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

My target json object is this.

```
"pencil": {
  "100": {
    "value": "#00000008",
    "type": "color"
  },
  "200": {
    "value": "#0000000d",
    "type": "color"
  },
  "300": {
    "value": "#0000001a",
    "type": "color"
},
```

I want change my javascipt object like this.

```
{
  "pencil": {
    "100": "#00000008",
    "200": "#0000000d",
    "300": "#0000001a",
  },
}
```

How do I change my object using javascript?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get an array of key / value pairs, [*map*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the values to the new ones and use [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to put it back together

```js
const target = {"pencil":{"100":{"value":"#00000008","type":"color"},"200":{"value":"#0000000d","type":"color"},"300":{"value":"#0000001a","type":"color"}}};

const mapped = {
  pencil: Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(target.pencil).map(([key, { value }]) => [key, value])
  ),
};

console.log(mapped);
```